# Wicket - changing panels through a dropdown

Tags: wicket

I have a dropdown component added on a page.  the purpose of this dropdown is to change the type of input form that is rendered.  for example, different forms have different required fields, editable fields, etc.

```
public final class Test extends WebPage
{

    CustomPanel currentPanel = new MeRequest("repeater",FormType.MIN);

    public Test(PageParameters parameters)
    {
        add(currentPanel);         

        DropDownChoice ddc = new DropDownChoice("panel", new PropertyModel(this, "selected"), panels, choiceRenderer);
        ddc.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                System.out.println("changed");
                currentPanel = new MeRequest("repeater",FormType.PRO);
                target.add(currentPanel);
            }
        });
        add(ddc);
    }
```

i've tried various options with limited results.  the only real success has been updating the model, but what i really want to do is change how the components behave.

any thoughts on what i'm missing?

Comment: Do you want to just replace one panel with the another?

Comment: yes, swap out 1 panel for another.  originally, i had loaded all panels (about 5) and used jquery to make only 1 visible, but i have some concerns about keeping things around in session that i wouldn't need or use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) If you want to replace one panel with another you may just do the following.

First of all, you should output the markup id of the original panel:

```
currentPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

And then in the ajax event handler write something like that:

```
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    CustomPanel newPanel = new MeRequest("repeater", FormType.PRO);
    currentPanel.replaceWith(newPanel);
    currentPanel = newPanel;
    currentPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    target.addComponent(currentPanel);
}
```

In this case with every change of dropdown choice you add new panel to the page and you remove old panel from the page.

2) But I would proposed a slightly different approach to your problem. You should move the construction logic of your panel to the onBeforeRender() method:

```
public class MeRequest extends Panel {

    private FormType formType;

    public MeRequest(String id, FormType formType) {
        super(id);
        this.formType = formType;

        // don't forget to output the markup id of the panel
        setOutputMarkupId(true);

        // constructor without construction logic
    }

    protected void onBeforeRender() {
        // create form and form components based on value of form type
        switch (formType) {
            case MIN:
                // ...
                break;
            case PRO:
                // ...
                break;
        }            

        // add form and form components to panel
        addOrReplace(form);
        form.add(field1);
        form.add(field2);
        // ...

        super.onBeforeRender();
    }

    public void setFormType(FormType formType) {
        this.formType = formType;
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to only change type of the panel in the ajax event:

```
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {        
    currentPanel.setFormType(FormType.PRO);
    target.addComponent(currentPanel);
}
```

Thus we rebuilt the original panel without recreating it.

Comment: But you'll still need `setOutputMarkupId(true)`.

Comment: @biziclop Do you mean the second approach? I added `setOutputMarkupId(true)` to the panel's constructor for the purpose of conciseness.

Comment: Oh yes, I can see it now, sorry.

Comment: after seeing this example, i took another look at the various classes making up the component structure.  as it turns out, i had about what you documented for 1), but was changing some component ids which appeared to be the main issue.  i do like option 2), but the actual Panel set up has 2 different Panel classes extending a custom base class (with a total of 5 instances).  while i type this, maybe the OnRender of the custom base class can be modified perform a similar function.  thanks for you detailed and prompt replies.

Comment: I would like to share a hint regarding this. I also hided one of my panles which was an "EmptyPanel". For this, because of setting visibility to false i had to replace setOutputMarkupId to setOutputMarkapPlaceholderTag.